# Why do TObject.AfterConstruction and BeforeConstruction have public visibility?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tobject

Today, one very simple question came to my mind when I had to override `TObject`'s `BeforeConstruction` method:

**Why do `TObject` methods `AfterConstruction` and `BeforeConstruction` have `public` visibility?**

I expected them to be `protected`.
What is the reason they aren't?

I can't imagine a valid purpose to call `AfterConstruction` or `BeforeConstruction` without calling the constructor or destructor of that class. Do you?

Comment: I'm sure this was asked (or maybe not asked, but answered)...

Comment: Likely the developer made a mistake

Comment: Oh, so [`it's been`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22540670/960757) about `TObject.InitInstance`, and does not directly answer what you ask. But as you can see, there's more that should've been protected but it's not. Taking back my initial comment...

Comment: Maybe, @DavidHeffernan is right with his assumption. Dr. Bob wrote [this](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi4/d4constr.htm) on Delphi 4. It says that these methods have been `protected` back then.

Comment: If they were protected but have been made public on a later date, it was very likely not a mistake, bur for a certain purpose.

Comment: Having the methods to be public allows you to intercept them using `TVirtualMethodInterceptor`

Comment: @Johan Virtual methods can be intercepted irrespective of their visibility.

Comment: I had a similar question once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540670/delphi-why-is-tobject-initinstance-public

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A previous question asked why some other methods are public instead of protected, and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545732/33732) was that they at some point needed to be called by utility functions that weren't attached to the class.

`TObject.AfterConstruction` is called by just such a utility function, `System._AfterConstruction`. If it were (strict) protected, then that standalone function wouldn't have access to the method.

*All* the methods of `TObject` are public.* We can probably find rationales to explain why each method is public, but at a certain point, I suspect that the underlying reason for any given method being public is that all the others are, too.

Once Delphi was released with those methods public, any reduction in their visibility would have risked breaking existing code.

---

* Except for `GetDisposed` and `CheckDisposed`, for some reason. They're relatively new, compared to the bulk of `TObject`.